# How to protect private key in non-root Docker Nginx

Tags: docker, nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate, private-key

I'm using the official non-root Docker Nginx image `nginxinc/nginx-unprivileged`

So the Q is, how to properly protect the private key when mounting via binding to the host's fs.
When you run such an image as a non-root user the private key has to be owned by that user as well. So in case of full control of that image, an attacker can see the private key.
When the standalone Nginx is used, it startup as root loads private key and changes the user, but this doesn't happen in docker.

I'm using the following config

docker-compose.yml:

```
services:
  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    image: nginxinc/nginx-unprivileged
    volumes:
      - ./src/code/:/var/www/html
      - /etc/ssl/certs/example.com.pem:/etc/ssl/certs/example.com.pem
      - /etc/ssl/private/example.com.key:/etc/ssl/private/example.com.key
    user: nginx
    ports:
      - 80:8080
      - 443:8443
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - int_net
```

THX for advice about how to secure an image under such circumstances.

Comment: If you have such concerns do not use docker. 
https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/#intermediate-example-use-secrets-with-a-nginx-service  This is for docker swarm for example.

Comment: What specific attack vector are you concerned with?  (Other processes on the same host?  Not trusting the process in the container?  Other human users who can run `docker` commands?)

Comment: @David let's say not trusting the processes in container. Those might came with know or unknown vulnerabilities allowing attackers somehow get into running ct.